# Android -Firebase Reauthenticate User for Phone Number Change

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

Users sign up using PhoneAuth. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75106392/4833705) there is a 5-minute window from when the user signs in until they can create a sensitive operation such as updating a phone number. The answer also says one option is to sign the user out and have them sign back in.

Without having the user sign out and sign back in, is there any benefit in using one of these over the other while the user is currently signed in?

```
val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, smsCode)


FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.reauthenticate(credential)
    .addOnCompleteListener {
    
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.updatePhoneNumber(credential) { ... }
    }
}

// or

FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential)
    .addOnCompleteListener(activity) {

    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.updatePhoneNumber(credential) { ... }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, when you call [FirebaseUser#updatePhoneNumber(PhoneAuthCredential credential)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#updatePhoneNumber(com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential)) it is mentioned that:

> Important: this is a security-sensitive operation that requires the user to have recently signed in. If this requirement isn't met, ask the user to authenticate again and later call reauthenticate(AuthCredential).

So you have to either sign the user out and right after that sign in, or reauthenticate the user. None of these options is better than the other. So you should choose, one or the other according to the use case of your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the phonenumber of a user signed in with PhonAuth firebase authentication, you can do it without signing out the current user, In Kotlin we have :

//With this you unlink the phonenumber of the user from his account in //Authentication but it does not delete his uid, just remove the phonenumber.
//You link the current user with the new phoneauthcredential you obtained with the //verification (I assume you know how to handle phonAuth)

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.unlink(PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID)
    .addOnSuccessListener{ 
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.linkWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential).addOnSuccessListener { 
    //Your desired behaviour 
            }
```

This worked fine for me after lot of hour of searches